# RStudio knit button error for download multiple files in RMarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

`download.file` function for multiple files works fine in console. It will return error when I click knit in RStudio to compile the code as a chunk of rmarkdown file.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/yufree/democode/blob/master/rreport/download.Rmd) Rmd file and the code is

```
options(timeout=600)
# Download demo data from figshare
name <- c('1.mzML','2.mzML')
url <- c("https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/25521071","https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/25521074")
download.file(url, name)
```

The code works fine in the console and will download two files. However, it will generate error in Rmd files when click knit in RStudio and the error is:

```
Quitting from lines 10-15 (download.Rmd) 
Error in download.file(url, name) : 
  'url' must be a length-one character vector
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> download.file
Execution halted
```

A temporary solution is using `for` loop:

```
options(timeout=600)
# Download demo data from figshare
name <- c('1.mzML','2.mzML')
url <- c("https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/25521071","https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/25521074")
for(i in c(1:2)){
        download.file(url[i], name[i])
}
```

I am sure it's not an issue from `knitr` package because the following code will work:

```
knitr::knit('download.Rmd')
```

However, I wonder why `download.file` doesn't work for multiple files in RStudio by clicking knit button?

Comment: I've only ever used `download.file` one URL & file at a time—it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me otherwise. The docs for it say "a character string (or longer vector e.g., for the "libcurl" method) naming the URL of a resource to be downloaded." Are you using libcurl? If not, it seems like you should be downloading one at a time

Comment: Beyond that, I've rarely seen issues of code running in the console but not in knitting markdown where the issue isn't related to scope: by default, knitting via the knit button (or I believe calling `rmarkdown::render`) creates a new temporary environment to run all the document's code. That makes your documents more reproducible because it requires the document to be self-contained. Refresh your session and see if the code still works in the console and/or document

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `rmarkdown::render` and it works fine to download multiple files(I believe rmarkdown also use knitr to render the document). It just doesn't work by clicking the button in RStudio and I have tried multiple times in many ways including restarting the session.

Comment: It seems the knit button will not use libcurl to download files. If I set the method as `libcurl`, the knit button will work. The default setting is `auto` and I think the knit button will select other method in the temporary environment.

Comment: You can set the method argument in your call to `download.file`